# Bootstrap3 add active class to first nav cannot work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I using Bootstrap in my website, I cannot add 'active' class to first nav li when I was browsing on that page, **ONLY** the first nav (Dashboard) have such issue, the rest of nav are working properly.

**Menu:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" id="side-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo baseurl ?>/cp/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo baseurl ?>/cp/agent-management"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Agent Management</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo baseurl ?>/cp/property-management"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Property Management</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./getout"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Sign Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

**Jquery:**

```
//highlight nav menu
$("#side-nav li a").each(function(index) {
    if($.trim(this.href) == window.location) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: `window.location` is the location object, not a string so the comparison will not work try `window.location.href`

Comment: @Arun P Johny, no luck, still the same after changing to window.location.href

Comment: Try $.trim( $(this).attr("href") ) == window.location.href